# If someone would want to think about the question: mathematical-optimization "Banknote"

Tags: list-manipulation, mathematical-optimization, probability-or-statistics, puzzle

I solved the puzzle of IBM Ponder This September 2019 by my code written with mathematica.
I would like to share this code after the solution that will come as soon, and discuss it.

In the meantime, if someone would want to think about the question.

September 2019 - Challenge
http://www.research.ibm.com/haifa/ponderthis/challenges/September2019.html

The problem:
The US dollar has five common banknote denominations: 1, 5, 10, 20, and 50.
Each integer dollar value between 0 and 99 dollars can be paid in a single way with a minimal number of notes.

If Alice and Bob have different amounts of money, they still can have the same set of notes.
For example, if Alice has  92 dollars and Bob has 74 dollars (in a minimal number of notes), they both have the same set of banknotes {1,20,50}.

Let's assume that Alice and Bob have two different amounts of money uniformly distributed in the [0.99] range with a minimal number of banknotes.
The probability that they are the same set of banknotes is approximately 3.79798%.

Your task, this month, is to find another set of five banknotes such that:

1-Each integer dollar value between 0 and 99 dollars can be paid in a single way with a minimal number of notes; and

### 2-The probability above (even set of banknotes for two different amounts of money uniformly distributed in the [0.99] range) would be exactly 4%.

My code is divided into 3 parts:

1 Functions.

2 Data.

### 3 Optimization. Solutions.

Comment: a first step: we can get numbers that share the same minimal set of notes using  `grouped=Select[Length@#>1&]@GroupBy[Range[99],Union@@MinimalBy[Length][ IntegerPartitions[#, All, {1, 5, 10, 20, 50}]]&]`

Comment: Re "1 - .. the amount of Alice and Bob can be zero":  0  can not be one of  _**two different amounts of money**_ sharing the same set of banknotes. Re 2--3: thank you for your understanding:)

Comment: "0 can not be one of two different amounts of money sharing the same set of banknotes".  Could you please give me an example.

Comment: Hy @kglr.

 There are also complicated questions, like This month November  2019 IBM PonderThis challanges. Who  talk about Latin and non Latin matrix:
 For now nobody has yet find the Solution of the Challange.
 https://www.research.ibm.com/haifa/ponderthis/challenges/November2019.html

This is the challange:
""This month's challenge is from Hugo Pfoertner (thanks!).
Find a 9x9 matrix that contains the digits 1..9, in which each digit appears exactly nine times, whose determinant is at least the hexadecimal number 0x3704d007 (LOOPhOLE upside down in hexadecimal)...."

Answer (score 1):

Module III : optimization the Challange September October 2019, Probabilty Value of  BankNotes selected.

```
AliceBob = 
 Permutations[Range[0, 99], {2}]; HyBankNotes = 65; BankNote = {}; BankNotes =
  Subsets[Range[2, HyBankNotes], {4}]; BankSave = 
 Select[BankNotes, #1[[1]] == 2 && 4 <= #1[[2]] <= 12 && 
    8 <= #1[[3]] <= 16 &]; c = 1; While[c != Length[BankSave], 
 AppendTo[BankNote, Insert[BankSave[[c]], 1, 1]]; c++]; q1 = 
 q2 = p = {}; S = 0; For[k = 1, k <= Length[BankNote], k++, NSolution1 = 0; 
 Dv = Reverse[BankNote[[k]]]; Dv1 = Reverse[Dv]; 
 For[x = 0, x <= 99, x++, 
  Res = s11 = 
    s12 = s13 = s14 = s15 = s1 = s2 = s3 = s4 = s5 = s16 = s6 = s17 = {}; 
  s7 = s18 = s8 = s19 = s9 = s011 = s01 = s012 = s02 = s014 = s04 = s016 = {};
   s06 = s017 = 
    s07 = s019 = 
      s09 = s0120 = 
        s020 = s0121 = 
          s021 = s0123 = 
            s023 = s0125 = 
              s025 = s0127 = 
                s027 = s0128 = 
                  s028 = s0129 = 
                    s029 = s0130 = 
                    s030 = s0131 = 
                    s031 = s0132 = 
                    s032 = s0133 = s033 = s0134 = s034 = s0135 = s035 = {}; 
  Notes1[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes2[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes3[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes4[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes5[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes7[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes9[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes11[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes12[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes14[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes16[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes17[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes19[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes20[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes21[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes23[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes25[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes27[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes28[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes29[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes30[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes31[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes32[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes33[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes34[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes35[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Sor = SortBy[{s11, s12, s13, s14, s15, s17, s19, s011, s012, s014, s016, 
     s017, s019, s0120, s0121, s0123, s0125, s0127, s0128, s0129, s0130, 
     s0131, s0132, s0133, s0134, s0135}, First]; 
  If[First[First[Sor[[1]]]] == First[First[Sor[[2]]]] && 
    Last[First[Sor[[1]]]] != Last[First[Sor[[2]]]], Goto[begin1]]; 
  Res = Last[First[Sor[[1]]]];
  For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++, If[Res[[i]] > 0, Res[[i]] = 1]]; A[x] = Res]; 
 NSolution1 = Length[Select[AliceBob, A[#1[[1]]] == A[#1[[2]]] &]]; 
 NSolution = NSolution1; AppendTo[p, NSolution]; 
 If[NSolution1 == 396, Goto[begin]]; 
 Label[begin1]]; Label[begin]; t = 3257; q1 = 
 q2 = p = {}; S = 0; g = 0; g1 = {}; g3 = 0; For[k = t, 
 k <= Length[BankNote], k++, NSolution1 = 0; Dv = Reverse[BankNote[[k]]]; 
 For[x = 0, x <= 99, x++, 
  Res = s11 = 
    s12 = s13 = s14 = s15 = s1 = s2 = s3 = s4 = s5 = s16 = s6 = s17 = {}; 
  s7 = s18 = s8 = s19 = s9 = s011 = s01 = s012 = s02 = s014 = s04 = s016 = {};
   s06 = s017 = 
    s07 = s019 = 
      s09 = s0120 = 
        s020 = s0121 = 
          s021 = s0123 = 
            s023 = s0125 = 
              s025 = s0127 = 
                s027 = s0128 = 
                  s028 = s0129 = 
                    s029 = s0130 = 
                    s030 = s0131 = 
                    s031 = s0132 = 
                    s032 = s0133 = s033 = s0134 = s034 = s0135 = s035 = {}; 
  Notes1[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes2[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes3[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes4[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes5[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes7[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes9[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes11[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes12[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes14[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes16[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes17[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes19[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes20[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes21[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes23[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes25[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes27[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes28[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes29[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes30[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes31[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes32[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes33[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes34[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes35[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Sor = SortBy[{s11, s12, s13, s14, s15, s17, s19, s011, s012, s014, s016, 
     s017, s019, s0120, s0121, s0123, s0125, s0127, s0128, s0129, s0130, 
     s0131, s0132, s0133, s0134, s0135}, First]; 
  If[First[First[Sor[[1]]]] == First[First[Sor[[2]]]] && 
    Last[First[Sor[[1]]]] != Last[First[Sor[[2]]]], Goto[begin2]]; 
  Res = Last[First[Sor[[1]]]];
  For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++, If[Res[[i]] > 0, Res[[i]] = 1]]; A[x] = Res]; 
 NSolution1 = Length[Select[AliceBob, A[#1[[1]]] == A[#1[[2]]] &]]; 
 NSolution2 = NSolution1; AppendTo[p, NSolution2]; 
 If[g < (100^2) / (NSolution2 + 100), g = (100^2) / (NSolution2 + 100); 
  g1 = Reverse[Dv]; g3 = NSolution1]; 
 Label[begin2]]; NSolution2 = 9900; Dv = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

The September question was extended on october 2019:

http://www.research.ibm.com/haifa/ponderthis/challenges/October2019.html:

Let's assume that Alice and Bob have two (possibly the same) integer amounts of money, uniformly distributed in the [0,99] range with a minimal number of banknotes.
Using the standard US dollar banknotes denominations of 1, 5, 10, 20, and 50, if the set of notes of Alice and Bob is the same - the probability of the amount being the same is about 21%.
Your task, this month, is to find the set of five banknote denominations that uniquely determines the set with the minimal number of notes while maximizing the above probability.

Solution with mathematica:

I made a video to show how the code works:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tpwrtEOLm-4

Answer (score 0):

Module 1  "Functions"  : The First optimization problem is to find Functions called "Notes1,Notes2... " such that Functions Minimize All the possibility for  diffferentes Banknotes. And prepare variables "s11,s12,.s011.." for  optimization the Challange in the Second Modules.

```
Notes1[d01_, d02_, d03_, d04_, d05_, n0p_] := 
 Module[{d1 = d01, d2 = d02, d3 = d03, d4 = d04, d5 = d05, S = n0p}, 
  m[1] = m[2] = m[3] = m[4] = m[5] = 0; 
  While[S != 0, 
   If[S >= d1, S = S - d1; m[1]++, 
    If[S >= d2, S = S - d2; m[2]++, 
     If[S >= d3, S = S - d3; m[3]++, 
      If[S >= d4, S = S - d4; m[4]++, S = S - d5; m[5]++]]]]]; 
  For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++, s1 = AppendTo[s1, m[i]]]; 
  AppendTo[s11, {Total[s1] 10^IntegerLength[5 - Count[s1, 0]] - 
     Count[s1, 0] + 5, s1}]]; 
Notes2[d01_, d02_, d03_, d04_, d05_, n0p_] := 
 Module[{d1 = d01, d2 = d02, d3 = d03, d4 = d04, d5 = d05, S = n0p}, 
  m[1] = m[2] = m[3] = m[4] = m[5] = 0; 
  While[S != 0, 
   If[S >= d2, S = S - d2; m[2]++, 
    If[S >= d3, S = S - d3; m[3]++, 
     If[S >= d4, S = S - d4; m[4]++, S = S - d5; m[5]++]]]]; 
  For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++, s2 = AppendTo[s2, m[i]]]; 
  AppendTo[s12, {Total[s2] 10^IntegerLength[5 - Count[s2, 0]] - 
     Count[s2, 0] + 5, s2}]]; 
Notes3[d01_, d02_, d03_, d04_, d05_, n0p_] := 
 Module[{d1 = d01, d2 = d02, d3 = d03, d4 = d04, d5 = d05, S = n0p}, 
  m[1] = m[2] = m[3] = m[4] = m[5] = 0; 
  While[S != 0, 
   If[S >= d3, S = S - d3; m[3]++, 
    If[S >= d4, S = S - d4; m[4]++, S = S - d5; m[5]++]]]; 
  For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++, s3 = AppendTo[s3, m[i]]]; 
  AppendTo[s13, {Total[s3] 10^IntegerLength[5 - Count[s3, 0]] - 
     Count[s3, 0] + 5, s3}]]; 
Notes4[d01_, d02_, d03_, d04_, d05_, n0p_] := 
 Module[{d1 = d01, d2 = d02, d3 = d03, d4 = d04, d5 = d05, S = n0p}, 
  m[1] = m[2] = m[3] = m[4] = m[5] = 0; 
  While[S != 0, 
   If[S >= d1, S = S - d1; m[1]++, 
    If[S >= d3, S = S - d3; m[3]++, 
     If[S >= d4, S = S - d4; m[4]++, S = S - d5; m[5]++]]]]; 
  For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++, s4 = AppendTo[s4, m[i]]]; 
  AppendTo[s14, {Total[s4] 10^IntegerLength[5 - Count[s4, 0]] - 
     Count[s4, 0] + 5, s4}]]; 
Notes5[d01_, d02_, d03_, d04_, d05_, n0p_] := 
 Module[{d1 = d01, d2 = d02, d3 = d03, d4 = d04, d5 = d05, S = n0p}, 
  m[1] = m[2] = m[3] = m[4] = m[5] = 0; 
  While[S != 0, 
   If[S >= d1, S = S - d1; m[1]++, 
    If[S >= d2, S = S - d2; m[2]++, 
     If[S >= d4, S = S - d4; m[4]++, S = S - d5; m[5]++]]]]; 
  For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++, s5 = AppendTo[s5, m[i]]]; 
  AppendTo[s15, {Total[s5] 10^IntegerLength[5 - Count[s5, 0]] - 
     Count[s5, 0] + 5, s5}]]; 
Notes7[d01_, d02_, d03_, d04_, d05_, n0p_] := 
 Module[{d1 = d01, d2 = d02, d3 = d03, d4 = d04, d5 = d05, S = n0p}, 
  m[1] = m[2] = m[3] = m[4] = m[5] = 0; 
  While[S != 0, 
   If[S >= d1, S = S - d1; m[1]++, 
    If[S >= d2, S = S - d2; m[2]++, 
     If[S >= d3, S = S - d3; m[3]++, S = S - d5; m[5]++]]]]; 
  For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++, s7 = AppendTo[s7, m[i]]]; 
  AppendTo[s17, {Total[s7] 10^IntegerLength[5 - Count[s7, 0]] - 
     Count[s1, 0] + 5, s7}]]; 
Notes9[d01_, d02_, d03_, d04_, d05_, n0p_] := 
 Module[{d1 = d01, d2 = d02, d3 = d03, d4 = d04, d5 = d05, S = n0p}, 
  m[1] = m[2] = m[3] = m[4] = m[5] = 0; 
  While[S != 0, 
   If[S >= d1, S = S - d1; m[1]++, 
    If[S >= d2, S = S - d2; m[2]++, S = S - d5; m[5]++]]]; 
  For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++, s9 = AppendTo[s9, m[i]]]; 
  AppendTo[s19, {Total[s9] 10^IntegerLength[5 - Count[s9, 0]] - 
     Count[s9, 0] + 5, s9}]]; 
Notes11[d01_, d02_, d03_, d04_, d05_, n0p_] := 
 Module[{d1 = d01, d2 = d02, d3 = d03, d4 = d04, d5 = d05, S = n0p}, 
  m[1] = m[2] = m[3] = m[4] = m[5] = 0; 
  While[S != 0, 
   If[S >= d1, S = S - d1; m[1]++, 
    If[S >= d4, S = S - d4; m[4]++, S = S - d5; m[5]++]]]; 
  For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++, s01 = AppendTo[s01, m[i]]]; 
  AppendTo[s011, {Total[s01] 10^IntegerLength[5 - Count[s01, 0]] - 
     Count[s01, 0] + 5, s01}]];
Notes12[d01_, d02_, d03_, d04_, d05_, n0p_] := 
  Module[{d1 = d01, d2 = d02, d3 = d03, d4 = d04, d5 = d05, S = n0p}, 
   m[1] = m[2] = m[3] = m[4] = m[5] = 0; 
   While[S != 0, If[S >= d1, S = S - d1; m[1]++, S = S - d5; m[5]++]]; 
   For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++, s02 = AppendTo[s02, m[i]]]; 
   AppendTo[s012, {Total[s02] 10^IntegerLength[5 - Count[s02, 0]] - 
      Count[s02, 0] + 5, s02}]];
Notes14[d01_, d02_, d03_, d04_, d05_, n0p_] := 
  Module[{d1 = d01, d2 = d02, d3 = d03, d4 = d04, d5 = d05, S = n0p}, 
   m[1] = m[2] = m[3] = m[4] = m[5] = 0; 
   While[S != 0, 
    If[S >= d2, S = S - d2; m[2]++, 
     If[S >= d3, S = S - d3; m[3]++, S = S - d5; m[5]++]]]; 
   For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++, s04 = AppendTo[s04, m[i]]]; 
   AppendTo[s014, {Total[s04] 10^IntegerLength[5 - Count[s04, 0]] - 
      Count[s04, 0] + 5, s04}]];
Notes16[d01_, d02_, d03_, d04_, d05_, n0p_] := 
  Module[{d1 = d01, d2 = d02, d3 = d03, d4 = d04, d5 = d05, S = n0p}, 
   m[1] = m[2] = m[3] = m[4] = m[5] = 0; 
   While[S != 0, 
    If[S >= d2, S = S - d2; m[2]++, 
     If[S >= d4, S = S - d4; m[4]++, S = S - d5; m[5]++]]]; 
   For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++, s06 = AppendTo[s06, m[i]]]; 
   AppendTo[s016, {Total[s06] 10^IntegerLength[5 - Count[s06, 0]] - 
      Count[s06, 0] + 5, s06}]];
Notes17[d01_, d02_, d03_, d04_, d05_, n0p_] := 
  Module[{d1 = d01, d2 = d02, d3 = d03, d4 = d04, d5 = d05, S = n0p}, 
   m[1] = m[2] = m[3] = m[4] = m[5] = 0; 
   While[S != 0, If[S >= d2, S = S - d2; m[2]++, S = S - d5; m[5]++]]; 
   For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++, s07 = AppendTo[s07, m[i]]]; 
   AppendTo[s017, {Total[s07] 10^IntegerLength[5 - Count[s07, 0]] - 
      Count[s07, 0] + 5, s07}]];
Notes19[d01_, d02_, d03_, d04_, d05_, n0p_] := 
  Module[{d1 = d01, d2 = d02, d3 = d03, d4 = d04, d5 = d05, S = n0p}, 
   m[1] = m[2] = m[3] = m[4] = m[5] = 0; 
   While[S != 0, 
    If[S >= d3, S = S - d3; m[3]++, 
     If[S >= d4, S = S - d4; m[4]++, S = S - d5; m[5]++]]]; 
   For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++, s09 = AppendTo[s09, m[i]]]; 
   AppendTo[s019, {Total[s09] 10^IntegerLength[5 - Count[s09, 0]] - 
      Count[s09, 0] + 5, s09}]];
Notes20[d01_, d02_, d03_, d04_, d05_, n0p_] := 
  Module[{d1 = d01, d2 = d02, d3 = d03, d4 = d04, d5 = d05, S = n0p}, 
   m[1] = m[2] = m[3] = m[4] = m[5] = 0; 
   While[S != 0, If[S >= d4, S = S - d4; m[4]++, S = S - d5; m[5]++]]; 
   For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++, s020 = AppendTo[s020, m[i]]]; 
   AppendTo[
    s0120, {Total[s020] 10^IntegerLength[5 - Count[s020, 0]] - 
      Count[s020, 0] + 5, s020}]];
Notes21[d01_, d02_, d03_, d04_, d05_, n0p_] := 
  Module[{d1 = d01, d2 = d02, d3 = d03, d4 = d04, d5 = d05, S = n0p}, 
   m[1] = m[2] = m[3] = m[4] = m[5] = 0; While[S != 0, S = S - d5; m[5]++]; 
   For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++, s021 = AppendTo[s021, m[i]]]; 
   AppendTo[s0121, {Total[s021] 10^IntegerLength[5 - Count[s021, 0]] - 
      Count[s021, 0] + 5, s021}]];
Notes23[d01_, d02_, d03_, d04_, d05_, n0p_] := 
  Module[{d1 = d01, d2 = d02, d3 = d03, d4 = d04, d5 = d05, S = n0p}, 
   m[1] = m[2] = m[3] = m[4] = m[5] = 0; 
   While[S != 0, If[S >= d3, S = S - d3; m[3]++, S = S - d5; m[5]++]]; 
   For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++, s023 = AppendTo[s023, m[i]]]; 
   AppendTo[s0123, {Total[s023] 10^IntegerLength[5 - Count[s023, 0]] - 
      Count[s023, 0] + 5, s023}]];
Notes25[d01_, d02_, d03_, d04_, d05_, n0p_] := 
  Module[{d1 = d01, d2 = d02, d3 = d03, d4 = d04, d5 = d05, S = n0p}, 
   m[1] = m[2] = m[3] = m[4] = m[5] = 0; 
   While[S != 0, If[S >= d4, S = S - d4; m[4]++, S = S - d5; m[5]++]]; 
   For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++, s025 = AppendTo[s025, m[i]]]; 
   AppendTo[s0125, {Total[s025] 10^IntegerLength[5 - Count[s025, 0]] - 
      Count[s025, 0] + 5, s025}]];
Notes27[d01_, d02_, d03_, d04_, d05_, n0p_] := 
  Module[{d1 = d01, d2 = d02, d3 = d03, d4 = d04, d5 = d05, S = n0p}, 
   m[1] = m[2] = m[3] = m[4] = m[5] = 0; While[S != 0, S = S - d5; m[5]++]; 
   For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++, s027 = AppendTo[s027, m[i]]]; 
   AppendTo[s0127, {Total[s027] 10^IntegerLength[5 - Count[s027, 0]] - 
      Count[s027, 0] + 5, s027}]];
Notes28[d01_, d02_, d03_, d04_, d05_, n0p_] := 
  Module[{d1 = d01, d2 = d02, d3 = d03, d4 = d04, d5 = d05, S = n0p}, a1 = 0; 
   m[1] = m[2] = m[3] = m[4] = m[5] = 0; 
   While[S != 0, 
    If[S >= d1 && a1 <= 1, a1 = a1 + 1; If[a1 == 1, S = S - d1; m[1]++], 
     If[S >= d2, S = S - d2; m[2]++, 
      If[S >= d3, S = S - d3; m[3]++, 
       If[S >= d4, S = S - d4; m[4]++, S = S - d5; m[5]++]]]]]; 
   For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++, s028 = AppendTo[s028, m[i]]]; 
   AppendTo[s0128, {Total[s028] 10^IntegerLength[5 - Count[s028, 0]] - 
      Count[s028, 0] + 5, s028}]];
Notes29[d01_, d02_, d03_, d04_, d05_, n0p_] := 
  Module[{d1 = d01, d2 = d02, d3 = d03, d4 = d04, d5 = d05, S = n0p}, a1 = 0; 
   m[1] = m[2] = m[3] = m[4] = m[5] = 0; 
   While[S != 0, 
    If[S >= d1 && a1 <= 2, a1 = a1 + 1; 
     If[a1 == 1 || a1 == 2, S = S - d1; m[1]++], 
     If[S >= d2, S = S - d2; m[2]++, 
      If[S >= d3, S = S - d3; m[3]++, 
       If[S >= d4, S = S - d4; m[4]++, S = S - d5; m[5]++]]]]]; 
   For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++, s029 = AppendTo[s029, m[i]]]; 
   AppendTo[s0129, {Total[s029] 10^IntegerLength[5 - Count[s029, 0]] - 
      Count[s029, 0] + 5, s029}]];
Notes30[d01_, d02_, d03_, d04_, d05_, n0p_] := 
  Module[{d1 = d01, d2 = d02, d3 = d03, d4 = d04, d5 = d05, S = n0p}, a1 = 0; 
   m[1] = m[2] = m[3] = m[4] = m[5] = 0; 
   While[S != 0, 
    If[S >= d1 && a1 <= 3, a1 = a1 + 1; 
     If[a1 == 1 || a1 == 2 || a1 == 3, S = S - d1; m[1]++], 
     If[S >= d2, S = S - d2; m[2]++, 
      If[S >= d3, S = S - d3; m[3]++, 
       If[S >= d4, S = S - d4; m[4]++, S = S - d5; m[5]++]]]]]; 
   For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++, s030 = AppendTo[s030, m[i]]]; 
   AppendTo[s0130, {Total[s030] 10^IntegerLength[5 - Count[s030, 0]] - 
      Count[s030, 0] + 5, s030}]];
Notes31[d01_, d02_, d03_, d04_, d05_, n0p_] := 
  Module[{d1 = d01, d2 = d02, d3 = d03, d4 = d04, d5 = d05, S = n0p}, a1 = 0; 
   m[1] = m[2] = m[3] = m[4] = m[5] = 0; 
   While[S != 0, 
    If[S >= d2 && a1 <= 1, a1 = a1 + 1; If[a1 == 1, S = S - d2; m[2]++], 
     If[S >= d3, S = S - d3; m[3]++, 
      If[S >= d4, S = S - d4; m[4]++, S = S - d5; m[5]++]]]]; 
   For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++, s031 = AppendTo[s031, m[i]]]; 
   AppendTo[s0131, {Total[s031] 10^IntegerLength[5 - Count[s031, 0]] - 
      Count[s031, 0] + 5, s031}]];
Notes32[d01_, d02_, d03_, d04_, d05_, n0p_] := 
  Module[{d1 = d01, d2 = d02, d3 = d03, d4 = d04, d5 = d05, S = n0p}, a1 = 0; 
   m[1] = m[2] = m[3] = m[4] = m[5] = 0; 
   While[S != 0, 
    If[S >= d2 && a1 <= 2, a1 = a1 + 1; 
     If[a1 == 1 || a1 == 2, S = S - d2; m[2]++], 
     If[S >= d3, S = S - d3; m[3]++, 
      If[S >= d4, S = S - d4; m[4]++, S = S - d5; m[5]++]]]]; 
   For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++, s032 = AppendTo[s032, m[i]]]; 
   AppendTo[s0132, {Total[s032] 10^IntegerLength[5 - Count[s032, 0]] - 
      Count[s032, 0] + 5, s032}]];
Notes33[d01_, d02_, d03_, d04_, d05_, n0p_] := 
  Module[{d1 = d01, d2 = d02, d3 = d03, d4 = d04, d5 = d05, S = n0p}, a1 = 0; 
   m[1] = m[2] = m[3] = m[4] = m[5] = 0; 
   While[S != 0, 
    If[S >= d2 && a1 <= 3, a1 = a1 + 1; 
     If[a1 == 1 || a1 == 2 || a1 == 3, S = S - d2; m[2]++], 
     If[S >= d3, S = S - d3; m[3]++, 
      If[S >= d4, S = S - d4; m[4]++, S = S - d5; m[5]++]]]]; 
   For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++, s033 = AppendTo[s033, m[i]]]; 
   AppendTo[s0133, {Total[s033] 10^IntegerLength[5 - Count[s033, 0]] - 
      Count[s033, 0] + 5, s033}]];
Notes34[d01_, d02_, d03_, d04_, d05_, n0p_] := 
 Module[{d1 = d01, d2 = d02, d3 = d03, d4 = d04, d5 = d05, S = n0p}, a1 = 0; 
  a2 = 0; m[1] = m[2] = m[3] = m[4] = m[5] = 0; 
  While[S != 0, 
   If[S >= d1 && a1 <= 2, a1 = a1 + 1; 
    If[a1 == 1 || a1 == 2, S = S - d1; m[1]++], 
    If[S >= d2 && a2 <= 2, a2 = a2 + 1; 
     If[a2 == 1 || a2 == 2, S = S - d2; m[2]++], 
     If[S >= d3, S = S - d3; m[3]++, 
      If[S >= d4, S = S - d4; m[4]++, S = S - d5; m[5]++]]]]]; 
  For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++, s034 = AppendTo[s034, m[i]]]; 
  AppendTo[s0134, {Total[s034] 10^IntegerLength[5 - Count[s034, 0]] - 
     Count[s034, 0] + 5, s034}]]; 
Notes35[d01_, d02_, d03_, d04_, d05_, n0p_] := 
 Module[{d1 = d01, d2 = d02, d3 = d03, d4 = d04, d5 = d05, S = n0p}, a1 = 0; 
  a2 = 0; m[1] = m[2] = m[3] = m[4] = m[5] = 0; 
  While[S != 0, 
   If[S >= d1 && a1 <= 2, a1 = a1 + 1; 
    If[a1 == 1 || a1 == 2, S = S - d1; m[1]++], 
    If[S >= d2 && a2 <= 1, a2 = a2 + 1; If[a2 == 1, S = S - d2; m[2]++], 
     If[S >= d3, S = S - d3; m[3]++, 
      If[S >= d4, S = S - d4; m[4]++, S = S - d5; m[5]++]]]]]; 
  For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++, s035 = AppendTo[s035, m[i]]]; 
  AppendTo[s0135, {Total[s035] 10^IntegerLength[5 - Count[s035, 0]] - 
     Count[s035, 0] + 5, s035}]];
...
```

Comment: watch my video to see the enchaingement of the secances of this programe:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tpwrtEOLm-4

Answer (score 0):

Module II "Screen Monitor to show progress value" : optimization the Challange IBM Ponder this September / October 2019              Probabilty Value of BankNotes .

```
g1 = {}; g = ""; g3 = 0; NSolution2 = 9900; {Solution September, 
 DynamicModule[{s = {{5, 30}, {1, Infinity}}}, 
  Deploy[Style[
    Panel[Grid[
      Transpose[{{Style["Solution Banknotes", Red], 
         Style["Probability : ", Red], "Quantiy of Solution", "", 
         ""}, {InputField[Dynamic[Dv1]], 
         InputField[Dynamic[N[NSolution/9900*100, 4]], Number, Enabled ->
           False], InputField[Dynamic[NSolution], Enabled -> False], 
         InputField[Dynamic[" "], Enabled ->
           False], InputField[Dynamic[""], Enabled -> False]}}], 
      Alignment -> Right], ImageMargins -> 10], 
    DefaultOptions -> {InputField -> {ContinuousAction -> True, 
        FieldSize -> s}}]]], "... Graph...", 
 Dynamic[ListPlot[p]], "... October Solution ...", 
 DynamicModule[{a = 0, b = 0, s = {{5, 30}, {1, Infinity}}}, 
  Deploy[Style[
    Panel[Grid[
      Transpose[{{Style["Solution Banknotes Max", Red], 
         Style["Max Probability : ", Red], 
         Style["Max Quantiy of Solution", Red], " Probability ", 
         "Banknotes"}, {InputField[Dynamic[g1]], 
         InputField[Dynamic[N[g, 4]], Number, Enabled ->
           False], InputField[Dynamic[g3], Enabled -> False], 
         InputField[Dynamic[N[100/(NSolution2 + 100)*100]], Enabled ->
           False], InputField[Dynamic[Reverse[Dv]], Enabled -> False]}}], 
      Alignment -> Right], ImageMargins -> 10], 
    DefaultOptions -> {InputField -> {ContinuousAction -> True, 
        FieldSize -> s}}]]]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Module 1V : Optimization the Challange September 2019 "Tester" Probabilty Value of one BankNotes selected.

```
AliceBob = Permutations[Range[0, 99], {2}]; Label[begin]; Bank = 
 DialogInput[{name = {}}, 
  Column[{"BankNotes", InputField[Dynamic[name], String], 
    Button["Proceed", DialogReturn[name], ImageSize -> Automatic]}]]; Bank = 
 Reverse[{ToExpression[
    StringCases[Bank, DigitCharacter ..]]}]; q1 = {}; q2 = {}; S = 0; For[
 k = 1, k <= Length[Bank], k++, Dv = Reverse[Bank[[k]]]; NSolution = 0; 
 For[x = 0, x <= 99, x++, 
  Res = s11 = 
    s12 = s13 = s14 = s15 = s1 = s2 = s3 = s4 = s5 = s16 = s6 = s17 = {}; 
  s7 = s18 = s8 = s19 = s9 = s011 = s01 = s012 = s02 = s014 = s04 = s016 = {};
   s06 = s017 = 
    s07 = s019 = 
      s09 = s0120 = 
        s020 = s0121 = s021 = s0123 = s023 = s0125 = s025 = s0127 = s027 = {};
   s0128 = s028 = 
    s0129 = s029 = 
      s0130 = s030 = 
        s0131 = s031 = 
          s0132 = s032 = s0133 = s033 = s0134 = s034 = s0135 = s035 = {}; 
  Notes1[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes2[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes3[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes4[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes5[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes7[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes9[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes11[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes12[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes14[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes16[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes17[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes19[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes20[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes21[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes23[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes25[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes27[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes28[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes29[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes30[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes31[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes32[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes33[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes34[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Notes35[Dv[[1]], Dv[[2]], Dv[[3]], Dv[[4]], Dv[[5]], x]; 
  Sor = SortBy[{s11, s12, s13, s14, s15, s17, s19, s011, s012, s014, s016, 
     s017, s019, s0120, s0121, s0123, s0125, s0127, s0128, s0129, s0130, 
     s0131, s0132, s0133, s0134, s0135}, First]; 
  If[First[First[Sor[[1]]]] == First[First[Sor[[2]]]] && 
    Last[First[Sor[[1]]]] != Last[First[Sor[[2]]]], 
   If[ChoiceDialog[" Solution:" Indeterminet] == True, Goto[begin], 
    Goto[end]]]; Res = Last[First[Sor[[1]]]];
  For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++, If[Res[[i]] > 0, Res[[i]] = 1]]; A[x] = Res]; 
 NSolution = Length[Select[AliceBob, A[#1[[1]]] == A[#1[[2]]] &]];]; If[
 ChoiceDialog[" Solution:"  N[NSolution/9900*100] "%"] == True, 
 Goto[begin]]; Label[end];
```